# Scalar multiplication of arrays with another array in numpy

Tags: numpy, vectorization

I have an array of arrays of size (4,1) like:

```
 ar1 = np.array([[1,1],
                [2,2],
                [3,3],
                [4,4]])
```

and a second array of size (1,2) like:

```
 ar2 = np.array([2,3])
```

I'm trying to multiply every first item of the first array times the first item of the second array, and every second item of the first array times the second item of the second array, such as the result is:

```
ar_result = np.array([[2,3],
                     [4,6],
                     [6,9],
                     [8,12]])
```

Is there a way to do this in an easy and vectorized way?

When I try to `ar1*ar2` it I'm getting this error:

`ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (2,)`

Thanks

EDIT: To clarify, in my case ar1 is a DataFrame df1 column or row, and ar2 is the content of a cell in another DataFrame df2 (`df2.loc[x,y] = [2,3]`)

Comment: The error tells you what the real shapes are, not what you think.  Print `ar1`. i suspect it is 1d object dtype.  The elements may be arrays, but might also be lists or strings.  With pandas it's hard to tell.

Comment: As shown you have a (4,2) and  (2,) which do multiply as desired.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried `ar1 * ar2`?

```
ar_result = ar1 * ar2
#array([[ 2,  3],
#       [ 4,  6],
#       [ 6,  9],
#       [ 8, 12]])
```

Comment: Yes but I'm getting this Value error: `ValueError: operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (4,) (2,)`. I've added an edit for clarification, might be the object type that is not exactly a `np.array`?